# Recovering deleted folder by GIT

Tags: git, recovery

I was stashing my code changes and GIT deleted my ignored folder /img/*, is there any way to recover the ignored folder?

Thanks a lot for answering!

Answer (score 1):

You can unstash the last stashed set of changes by running the following: `git stash pop`.

If the files were removed as part of the stash process then that should get them back for you.

I have a hunch though that they didn't get deleted by the stash. Stashes by default, without any flags, will leave ignored files alone.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `git` doesn't delete any of your stuff. I am guessing you have done the following:

1. Create a folder and add some stuff into the folder
2. Now, you want to stash the changes you have made and you have run `git
   stash`.
3. `git stash` helps you in stashing the changes which you have recently made.
4. So, that means it stashed the recent folder creation (which is a change)
5. Now, if you do `git stash pop` you will get back the changes which means you will see your folder again.